# How do I use Google Pub/Sub Lite with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

How do I use Google Pub/Sub Lite with Node.js?

There is a library for the full global version but nothing for the lite version. npm only has 'lite' wrappers for the full global version of Pub/Sub.

Is it possible to use the full Pub/Sub library with some settings changes or something like that? or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no NodeJS client library available for Pub/Sub Lite according to this official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-go). The Pub/Sub Lite client libraries are only available in Go, Java and Python languages.

Comment: The library to which you link is *not* for Pub/Sub Lite. It is a third-party "lite" wrapper around the Cloud Pub/Sub library.

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn Thanks kamal for clarifying this I edited the answer based on your comment.

Comment: I asked google pub/sub team. They said they'd discuss it in their weekly meeting.

Comment: Absurd.. just absurd